# Division by 10 in hexadecimal

Tags: c, math, division

I need to separate the last 6 decimal positions of hexadecimal number from the rest of the number.

Division with 10 in decimal is the same like right shift 4 times (x >> 4) in hexadecimal.
I tried to shift right but I never get the correct value.

```
Hex: 0x7A 11F8 5EE0
Dec: 524.297.500.000
```

I want to separate the last 6 decimal position into a new variable:

```
524.297.500.000 -> 524.297
a = 524.297
b = 500.000
```

```
repeat time
    0x7A 11F8 5EE0 >> 4
```

I am working with hexadecimal numbers.

Questions:

1. How many times shall I shift right to cut the last 6 decimal position?
2. Is bit shifting (division by 10) faster in binary or in hexadecimal?

Comment: Shifting right by 4 is dividing by 16, regardless of the number system in which the external (string) representations takes place.

Comment: `0x7A 11F8 5EE0` is `524'287'500'000` in decimal.

Comment: There are no decimal or hexadecimal numbers. There are just numbers. But you can _represent_ the numbers in hexadecimal, in decimal, in octal, in binary or whatever other base.

Comment: Decimal, hexadecimal, or even octal are just presentational. All values on a binary computer are stored in binary.

Comment: unclear what you want. a number is always the same number no matter the base it is **represented** in. `17` oranges is the same as `0x11` oranges or `0b10001` oranges.

Comment: You will need to read the hex digits into a long enough integer variable and do the division there.

Comment: For your problem, just use division and module with (decimal) `1000000` to get the result you want.

Comment: bit shifting to the right 4 times is deviding by 16, not by 10.

Comment: You'll never be able to divide by 10 decimal using bit shifts alone.

Comment: @FredLarson No problem, you have to shift by `3.3219280948873623478703194294893901759...` places ;)

Comment: @Ctx: Example code, please. 8vD

Comment: @Ctx: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: My computer used BCD (binary coded decimals) so I can bit shift to divide by 10.

Answer (score 0):

As the various comments say, shifting is not going to achieve what you want.  And what you want is itself unclear!

However, you can achieve what it looks like you need with conventional division and modulo operators.  Something like:

```c
int x = 524297500;
int a = x / 1000; // 524297
int b = x % 1000; // 500
```

This is just a quick-and-dirty answer.  Also, you'll notice I used a smaller number than you and separated the bottom 3 (not 6) decimal places.  That's just because your example was too big to fit in an int (very often 32-bits long) and I wanted to show the idea, not the gritty details of the integer type system.

Answer (score 0):

[all numbers decimal]

*If* you (for whatever reason) need to divide an integer by 10 using bit shifting you 1st need to convert the integer to be divided into its [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) representation.

Depending on whether you used BCD or packed BCD you needed to shift to the right by 8 bit or 4 bit to divide by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Separately, *shifting* by some number of places is the same as dividing by the place value.  I wonder if that's where your confusion comes from.

Consider this case *in decimal*:

```
value: 213423
shifted right by one digit: 21342  (the 3 gets discarded)
```

We can see this is the same as dividing by 10 and rounding down:

```
value: 213423
divide by 10: 21342.3
round down: 21342
```

The shift by one digit and the divide by 10 give the same answer because each digit has a place-value of 10.

Now *in hexadecimal* each digit has a place value of 16 (in decimal), so shifting right by one hex digit is the same as dividing by 16 (in decimal).

Finally, *in binary* each digit has a place-value of two, so shifting by one digit is the same as dividing by two (in decimal).  And because of how binary works, shifting by four is the same as dividing by 16 (in decimal).

So everyone is correct in saying something like "a number isn't decimal or hex, but you can *represent* a number as decimal or hex".  But the shift operation is connected to the representation.  A shift by 1  in decimal is the same as divide by 10.  The final wrinkle is that in C, your *only* choice is shifting in binary, which is equaivalent to the decimal division by 2, 4, 8, 16...

I hope this helps rather than muddying the waters further!